# How to update props of initial route in a NavigatoriOS component?

Tags: navigation, react-native

This question is about strategies for passing data objects around several components.

In the screenshot below, I have a **NavigatorIOS** with an initial route of a **ListComponent**. Its in a **Side-Menu** that displays a **Filters** component. Currently, the **Side-Menu** is open and **Filters** is visible.

My goal is that when the user changes things in **Filters**, I want to update the **ListComponent**.

I could use a singleton object to store filters, but I still need to find a way to tell the **ListComponent** that they changed.

[image]

```
var defaultFilters = {
invited: true,
joined: false,
public: true,
private: false,
}

class MainTab extends Component {

constructor( props ){
    super(props);

    this.props.filters = defaultFilters;
}

render () {

    var onFilterChange = function ( filters ) {
        console.log("filters changed");
    };

    var filtersComponent = ( <Filters filters={this.props.filters} onFilterChange={onFilterChange.bind(this)} /> );

    return (
        <SideMenu menu = { filtersComponent } touchToClose={true} openMenuOffset={300} animation='spring'>
            <NavigatorIOS 
                style={styles.container}
                initialRoute={{
                    title: 'List',
                    component: ListComponent
                }}

                />
        </SideMenu>
    );
}
}
```

## Solved

```
    var onFilterChange = function ( filters ) {
        console.log("filters changed");

        this.refs.navigator.replace({
            title: 'List',
            component: ListComponent,
            passProps: {
              filters: filters
            }
          });
    };

   <NavigatorIOS 
            ref='navigator'
            ...
            />
```

Comment: You should post your answer as... an answer, because that's the right one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The route has a `passProps` option which accepts an object of props, so that's how you pass props into the component in the navigator. You could potentially change your `MainTab` state in `onFilterChange` and pass that down via `passProps`. Alternatively you may want to look at the `replace` method on the navigator.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigatorios.html

Comment: For context, see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/795. So, I won't be able to have the `ListComponent` automatically render from a state change in the `MainTab`. However, using your suggestion of replace, I got it to work. I'll add my solution above. Thanks again, Colin!

Comment: Colin, it also turns out that when you try to `replace` with the same component, nothing will happen. Right now I'm duping it by toggling between two different components of the same exact code so that I can make my list appear to auto-filter. Later, I will be posting a new stackoverflow question detailing my hack and asking for thoughts on a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using the OP, [joshua-lieberman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1930489/joshua-lieberman), same response.

It worked for me using **Navigator**

```
var onFilterChange = function ( filters ) {
    console.log("filters changed");

    this.refs.navigator.replace({
        title: 'List',
        component: ListComponent,
        passProps: {
          filters: filters
        }
      });
};
...
        <Navigator
        ref='navigator'
        ...
        />
```

I use it in **componentDidMount**

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.changeInitialRoute(this.refs.navigator);
}

changeInitialRoute(navigator) {
    const valet = this.props.valet;
    if (valet && valet.user_id && valet.token) {
        console.log('valet ready', this.props);
        navigator.resetTo({title: 'Home', index: 0});
    } else {
        navigator.resetTo({title: 'Login', index: 0});
    }
}
```